# react-dnd unable to drag element

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have a react drag and drop front end to a board game. And I am finding that In certain circumstances I cannot drag pieces that I expect to be draggable.

I have been able to reproduce a similar situation with a minor tweak to [the react-dnd Chessboard sample](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/00%20Chessboard/Tutorial%20App) as follows.

I cloned the latest react-dnd repository, and made sure the knight in the Chessboard example can be moved as expected. Then I edited the file BoardSquare.js of the example to return true all the time for canDrop:

```js
const squareTarget = {
    canDrop(props) {
    return true;
    // return canMoveKnight(props.x, props.y);
},
```

Now when I bring up the application, I cannot drag the knight. I am not sure why a more permissive drop strategy leads to an inability to drag.

Any ideas on what is happening here and how to fix my problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Azad

P.S. Using Chrome 58 on MAC OS/X.

Comment: Can you provide more of the code that you're working on? I can't see what's wrong with what you've done with just that code.

Comment: As I mentioned, all I did was to change the file BoardSquare.js of the react dnd chess board example, and replace the code for canDrop as specified in my initial post. If you like I can post that entire file. But in order to reproduce the problem, you'd have to copy the entire chessboard sample, which includes that file. So I am not sure it will help to post it. But please let me know.